# CASE** returns the result of the **first**

Tags: sql, denodo

I am trying to do some **case** statement in my **SQL**. Below example shows what I want to do.

**Example**

```
case WHEN p = 1 THEN 'SOMETHING' 
     WHEN p = 1 AND q = 1 THEN 'SOMETHING ELSE'
```

Here, **CASE** returns the result of the **first** WHEN clause that evaluates to **true**. In this example , the **first** and **second** WHEN conditions are **true**, but returns the result of the **first** **one**.

Comment: Yes. What is your question?

Comment: Its a `if and else case` not an `if in if` case thaf means if the top is true then theres no need to go further rather in the latter if first is true then again check if it meets further more conditions (if in if) as in your case `CASE WHEN p=1 Then (Case When q=1 Then "correct" End Case ) Else "incorrect" End Case `

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`CASE` is always executed sequentially. Just change the order of the `WHEN` clauses to get what you want:

```
case WHEN p = 1 AND q = 1 THEN 'SOMETHING ELSE'
     WHEN p = 1 THEN 'SOMETHING' 
end
```

Comment: Maybe you should fix the syntax here and include `END`?

Comment: @Hogan Point taken.

Comment: Actually 10 points for the upvote. :D

Comment: The fun thing is that the OP never said that they want to return the result of the second `when`.

Comment: @GSerg -- that is why he gets my vote since he was able to ready minds.

Comment: Thanks @TheImpaler